# SQLAlchemy ORDER BY FIELD()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort an SQLAlchemy ORM object by a field, but with a specific order of the values (which is neither ascending or descending).  If I was doing this query on MySQL, it would look like;

```
SELECT letter FROM alphabet_table WHERE letter in ('g','a','c','k')
ORDER BY FIELDS( letter, 'g','a','c','k');
```

for the output:

```
letter
------
  g
  a
  c
  k
```

For SQLAlchemy, I've been trying things along the lines of:

session.query(AlphabetTable).filter(AlphabetTable.letter.in_(('g','a','c','k'))).order_by(AlphabetTable.letter.in_(('g','a','c','k')))

Which doesn't work... any ideas? It's a small one-time constant list, and I could just create a table with the order and then join, but that seems like a bit too much.

Comment: Can you call a mysql stored procedure from the sqlalchemy ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may not be a very satisfying solution, but how about using a [case expression](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) instead of `order by fields`:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.Query(AlphabetTable) \
    .filter(AlphabetTable.letter.in_("gack")) \
    .order_by(sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case(((AlphabetTable.letter == "g", 1),
                                              (AlphabetTable.letter == "a", 2),
                                              (AlphabetTable.letter == "c", 3),
                                              (AlphabetTable.letter == "k", 4))))
```

Answer (score 15):

A sqlalchemy [func expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) can be used to generate the `order by field` clause:

```
session.query(AlphabetTable) \
    .filter(AlphabetTable.letter.in_("gack")) \
    .order_by(sqlalchemy.func.field(AlphabetTable.letter, *"gack"))
```